# What is the equation of a sphere of radius R centred at the origin in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I said that $r = R, -R \leq z \leq R$, and  $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Saying that $r = R$ is incorrect, however, but I don't understand why because clearly, at all points of the sphere the radius is $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rectangular coordinates the equation is
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$
For cylindrical coordinates, z stays as is, and $r^2=x^2+y^2$.
So you have
$$r^2+z^2=R^2$$
Remember that for cylindrical coordinates r is a distance to the z axis, not the distance to the origin.

Comment: How do you get $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$?

Comment: Nevermind, I see how, thanks!